# How to read a parquet file with lots of columns to a Dataset without a custom case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I want to use datasets instead of dataframes.

I'm reading a parquet file and want to infer the types directly:

```
val df: Dataset[Row] = spark.read.parquet(path)
```

I don't want `Dataset[Row]` but a `Dataset`.

I know I can do something like:

```
val df= spark.read.parquet(path).as[myCaseClass]
```

but, my data has many columns! so, if I can avoid writing a case class it would be great!

Comment: You can select the columns you want before you convert it into a `DataSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to work with a `Dataset`? I think it's because you will have not only the schema for free (which you have with the result `DataFrame` anyway) but because you will have a type-safe schema.

You need to have an `Encoder` for your dataset and to have it you need a type that would represent your dataset and hence the schema.

Either you `select` your columns to a reasonable number and use `as[MyCaseClass]` or you should accept what `DataFrame` offers.

Comment: thank you Jacek. It makes sense.

I didn't want to deal with the `Row` in mapping fields. Example. Say I want to extract the row with the maximum value:

If I have a `DataFrame`:
`val maxMetric = metricsCurve.orderBy($"metric".desc).head()`

Then to access the elements of maxMetric (which is a `Row`), I have to do something like:
`maxMetric.getAs[Double]("precision")`

But, if metricsCurve is a DataSet I then can do:
`maxMetric.precision ` since maxMetric is an instance of the class